# How to save the data of a symbol list like SNP 500 that was downloaded from yfinance to the csv files and then add just the current date and repeat

Tags: python, pandas, csv, yfinance

Hi i am building a tool to download stock data from Yfinance and i want to download the historic data once,save it to vs files in a directory and then every day just add the last trading day(one row) and resave it..the problem is that the csv files are overwritten from scratch so if i provide just the last trading day to be downloaded, that will be all the rows i will end up with for each symbol.
The code that i work with is in two parts.. first to create the dataframe in pandas and then save it with all my new funtions included  and then get the data frame in any other project that i want, from the directory it was saved.
I also have a second question regarding wheather this is good practice to work with csv files and pandas dataframe ,instead of sqlite database and what are the pros and cons between the different methods.

Part 1
Create the directory and csv files

```
import yfinance as yf
import os
import pandas as pd


with open(r'C:\zPythonFilesDir\yfinance\symbolstest.csv') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    #print(lines)
    for symbol in lines:
        print(symbol)
        data = yf.download(symbol, start="2023-07-01", end="2023-07-30")
        #print(data)
        data.to_csv(r'C:\zPythonFilesDir\yfinance\datasetstest\{}.csv'.format(symbol))

for filename in os.listdir(r'C:\zPythonFilesDir\yfinance\datasetstest'):
    #print(filename)
    symbol = filename.split(".")[0]
    print(symbol)
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\zPythonFilesDir\yfinance\datasetstest/{}'.format(filename))
    # new columns and functions here
    x = 2 * round(df['High'],2)
    df['new_val'] = x
    # write new datasets with functions columns in different directory
    df.to_csv(r'C:\zPythonFilesDir\yfinance\newdatasetstest\{}.csv'.format(symbol))
    print(df)
```

Part 2
Get the data from csv files

```
import os
import pandas as pd


for filename in os.listdir(r'C:\zPythonFilesDir\yfinance\newdatasetstest'):
    #print(filename)
    symbol = filename.split(".")[0]
    print(symbol)
    df1= pd.read_csv(r'C:\zPythonFilesDir\yfinance\newdatasetstest/{}'.format(filename))
    print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\zPythonFilesDir\yfinance\newdatasetstest/AAPL.csv')
print(df2)
```

The symbolstest.csv is having the symbols of interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data frame default to_csv method use write mode when opening file what you need to do is change it to append, which can be done with.

```
    SAVE_TO_PATH = r'C:\zPythonFilesDir\yfinance\newdatasetstest\{}.csv'.format(symbol)
    df.to_csv(SAVE_TO_PATH, mode='a', header=False)
```

I also moved path outside function arguments for readability and set header to false as we don't want to append them everyday

btw it is cSV(comma separated values) not cVS.

bottom line is to use mode='a' when you want to add lines to existing file or use mode='w' when you are adding for the first time/want to overwrite file.(mode='w' is default so you dont have to specify it)

Comment: Great thanks a lot..by the way i am trading this stock CVS lately , so i guess its inprinted in my mind lately!https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/cvs

Comment: Please mark it as accepted answer to help other with same problem in the future. btw CVS looks like double top for me 1D

Comment: i will...what is your opinion about using csv files and pandas instead of a database ta access stock data and indicators..i am building a streamlit app to showcase my proprietary code and ideas but i don't know which way to go..the csv files and pandas looks like a shortcut to the database to me..what are the pros and cons of each solution if you don't mind..

Comment: It depends what exactly you are trying to build, I had ideas around trading as well so f.e. one was to grab accounts from different brokers in one place, add points on chart where I made transactions etc. So for project of this kind I will deffinitly go with db, but some simple scripts can go with csv. Like if you planning to maintain this csv file for days you have to remember it will become huge. So for every operation you want to do on some row in a file will require to go through whole file(not excatly but it is costly).

Comment: bottom line is use db when: you can anticipate that your csv can be accessed from many sources in the same time(for example other script), db can easily handle parallel access. You often do operations on rows, you need to create relations between data, you work with large dataset. To be honest as you want to update your csv daily I would already go with db, as csv will become huge in a matter of time. If you don't need relations between your data you can use some nosql db also

Comment: thanks for the advice! there is a new problem though..a new column called unnamed : 0 has been inserted when i use " a" and its the old index of the data frame witch ends at some number when i use "w" and then starts from 0 when i use " a " the correct index appears when i get the data frame as df1 but it also has this new column!

Comment: I think the best for you will be to get into df to_csv method documentation or even source code and see how it works and what it is on your own